# Reading two lines of input and then splitting

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am working on an assignment in which I need to read 2 seperate lines from the console, store it in a single variable, and later have the ability to split it.

Sample input:

'5'
'Firstname'

The first line of input needs to be casted to an integer, and the second a string. So you will end up with:
5 - int
"Firstname" - String

I have tried using the `String.split()` method but I'm not sure how to split by line breaks.

Comment: The best way to do it is to go and write some code .

Comment: If you are splitting by lines, then use `identifier.split("\n");` if the input actually contains the newline character.

Comment: I have written the whole program. Since I am a beginner I am stuck with this. I actually wrote two separate variables to get inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is quite simple.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int line1 = 0;

    while (true) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.length > 0) {
            try {
                line1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Input not an integer, try again.");
            }
        } else {
            // User entered nothing. Break loop to stop it from never ending.
            break;
        }
    }
    String line2 = Scanner.nextLine();
}
```

This will store an integer from the scanner, and forcefully make sure it is an integer, and then store a string afterwards. If you do not correctly enter an integer, it will request another.

If you need to later split the string for every whitespace, use:

```
String[] array = line2.split(" ");
```

You cannot split an Integer.

If both inputs need to be combined into a single string, then you can then use:

```
String completeString = line1 + " " + line2;
```

And again, you can split this by using:

```
String[] array = completeString.split(" ");
```

So if the user entered 55, and "Hello", you would end up with the following after splitting:

```
["55", "Hello"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanenr scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
String[] th = input.split(" ");

//After splitting
int a = Integer.parseInt(th[0]);  //5
String b = th[1]; //FirstName
```

Comment: You will get an error. You can't automatically cast from String to int.

Comment: @frayment Sorry typo dude !

Comment: Have you got any type-checking to ensure that the integer correctly parses? See my answer. ;)

Comment: refer @frayment - you need to use try catch clause !

Comment: @frayment i was not telling you, @ playstonerasked how to validate stuff so i told him to refer your answer !

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. My apologies. :)